# Projection on hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

This is a problem i came across studying for a functional analysis course.

Consider a Hilbert space $H$ a non-zero vector $v\in H$ and a bounded linear functional $ f :H \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ .
The point is to show that $P:H \longrightarrow H $ with $$Pu=f(u)v$$ is an orthogonal projection iff $f(v)=1$.

Ok the one direction is easy.Assuming that $P$ is a projection  we only need idempotence to prove that $f(v)=1$.For the other direction i thought that i could coclude that the norm of $P$ equals to $1$.
Considering a $y=\frac{v}{||v||}\in S^{1}_{H}$ (the surface of the unit sphere in H) we have that $||Py||=\frac{1}{||v||}|f(v)|||v||=1$ .
So $$||P||\geq 1$$Now i thought that assuming $||P||>1$ would somehow contradict that $f$ is bounded but i can't get there.

Maybe proving another equivalent condition of $P$ being a projection like orthogonality of $kerP,imP$ or $P=P^*$ would be easier.

Any thoughts would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $v,w$ are orthogonal unit vectors, and let $f(u)=(u,v+w)$. Then $f$ is a continuous linear functional and $f(v)=1$. So $Pv=f(v)v=v$. In order for $P$ to be an orthogonal projection, it is necessary and sufficient that $(z-Pz)\perp \mathcal{R}(P)$, where $\mathcal{R}(P)$ is the range of $P$. Because the range of $P$ is $[\{ v\}]$, which is the subspace generated by the vector $v$, that means $P$ is an orthogonal projection iff $(z-Pz)\perp v$ for all $z\in H$. However,
\begin{align}
      (v+w-P(v+w),v) &=((v+w)-(v+w,v+w)v,v)\\
        &=1-(v+w,v+w) \\
        &= 1-2\ne 0.
\end{align}
So you are missing some statement in your problem, or the problem appears to me to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you take $f(x) = x_1$, $v = (1,1)^T$, then $f(v) = 1$ and 
$P= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ which is not
orthogonal since $P \neq P^*$.

The problem statement if correct if you remove the word orthogonal.